# Javascript Promise object with GWT JsInterop

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have this code that I want to use to init() a third-party Javascript library:

```
@JsType(namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, name = "Kinvey", isNative = true)
public class Kinvey {
    public String appKey;
    public String appSecret;
    public static native void init();
}
```

The problem is the `init` function returns a Javascript Promise object, **how can GWT deal with this object using JsInterop?**

```
var promise = Kinvey.init({
    appKey    : 'your_app_key',
    appSecret : 'your_app_secret'
});
promise.then(function(activeUser) {
    ...
}, function(error) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example is use to return JS promises from GWT code, but you can adapt it for your scenario, it just wraps the `Promise` Javascript class with its Java counterpart class, declaring also `then()` and `catch()` methods:

```
@JsType(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class Promise {

  @JsFunction
  public interface FunctionParam {
      void exec(Object o);
  }

  @JsFunction
  public interface ConstructorParam {
      void exec(FunctionParam resolve, FunctionParam reject);
  }

  @JsConstructor
  public Promise(ConstructorParam parameters) {
  }

  public Promise then(FunctionParam f) { }

  public Promise catch(FunctionParam f) { }
}
```

Comment: catch is a special keyword in Java, how do you workaround this?

Comment: `@JsMethod(name="catch") public Promise catch_(…` Though I'd recommend using jsinterop-core (or is it jsinterop-core?) nowadays.