# Passing a Java callback in GWT to JSNI method which returns a Promise?

Tags: gwt, gxt, jsni

I am new to Promises and need some advice on how to handle a returned Promise in a JSNI method called from Java. 
Can't use JsInterop due to older version 2.7 of GWT.
Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Promise object with GWT JsInterop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717870/javascript-promise-object-with-gwt-jsinterop)

Comment: Thats correct, however GWT JSInterop is supported from GWT 2.8 and I am still using GWT 2.7 and will not upgrade. Any pointers on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have to read properties on the return object, you may try 
treating it as `JSONObject`.

Alternatively you could call a method of your Java object in the resolver function of the promise to check conditions to decide if you want to resolve/reject.
`p.then()` could be called with `onFulfilled`/`onRejected` functions just wrapping Java method calls to handle the result.

**Example:**

```
public class PromiseWrapper {

    boolean evaluate(String value) {
        return value != null ? true : false;
    }

    void onFulfilled(String value) {
        // use value
    }

    void onRejected(Strin reason) {
        // use reason
    }

    public native void doSomethingAynchronously() /*-{
        var p = new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject) {
                var value = null; // Get value from somewhere
                if(this.@com.company.project.PromiseWrapper::evaluate(Ljava/lang/String;)(value)) {
                    resolve(value);
                }
                else {
                    reject("Because");
                }
            }
        );
        p.then(function(value) {
                this.@com.company.project.PromiseWrapper::onFulfilled(Ljava/lang/String;)(value);
            }, 
            function(reason) {
                this.@com.company.project.PromiseWrapper::onRejected(Ljava/lang/String;)(reason);
            }
        );
    }-*/;

}
```

This is an untested example.